# Why the unreasonable effectiveness of simple brute-force attack on LWE Lattice Secret Key?

Tags: lwe, fortuna

Exploring LWE Lattice crypto. Generate system matrix and secret key from cryptographic PRNG (Fortuna). Derive public key as |p> = A|s>, then add NBits of zero mean uniform noise to the public key elements, producing |p'>. Publish (|p'>, A).

System matrix, A, has been defined with NRows = 128, matching a 128-bit element size in a prime field of modulus u=(2^128-159). NCols = 120. Density is very close to 1.

Simple minded first attempt at cracking (|p'>,A) to obtain a secret key - just solve blocks of NCols = 120 rows of the matrices, for 9 of them starting at row 0 and ending at row 8. So we have 9 potential decryption keys to start off.

Run a gazillion encryptions with random row selections, averaging NRows/2 selected rows. On each encryption of message zero, try to crack it with one of the 9 provisional secret key candidates.

Encryption cryptotext = (b, <v|), where b = m*Floor(u/2) + <r|p'> mod u, <v| = <r|A mod u, for random selection vector <r|, message m, prime modulus u.

Decryption:  msg = Floor((b - <v|s> + Floor(u/4)) mod u)/Floor(u/2))

There will usually be residual noise after performing: (b - <v|s> mod u, even with the correct secret key, s. And definitely large residual most of the time with these provisional cracks.

But I'm finding that decryption using at least one of the 9 provisional keys does work, unreasonably well, getting zero residual noise in the decryption computation of (b - <v|s'>). This zero residual shows up with a mean interval of 450 encryptions, looking very much like Poisson distribution with mean interval between successful crackings roughly equal to the standard deviation. When one of the 9 s', it often happens that several others also work for the same decryption.

The candidate keys are not equal to the secret key, s. But they seem even more effective in those successful crackings, leaving no noise. The rest of the time, their decryptions show residuals of O(u) as you would expect.

I have tried with 6-bits, then 12-bits, of additive noise on the public key. Statistics of cracking don't seem to depend on the size of the noise field.

We have in each case, an effective random noise protection key given by NCols*NNoise, for 720 bits, then 1440 bits. So cracks ought to be more nearly impossible, no?

Is Fortuna possibly broken here? Why should this stupid simple approach work so well?

Comment: Fortuna is a RNG unrelated to LWE. A simple test can decide if it's part of the alleged surprising decryption : replace what Fortuna generates by the output of SHA-256 for incremental input (over the whole set of experiments). If the surprising decryption remains, remove the Fortuna part of the question (and clarify it's LWE part). If the surprising decryption vanishes, Fortuna or (more likely) your use of it is broken.

Comment: I don't believe that Fortuna is broken. Instead, I had system parameters producing a fat overdetermined system with N Equations just slightly larger than N Unknowns, instead of vastly overdetermined as per recommendations N Eqn >> N Unk.

The nature of such systems seems to gradually approach that of underdetermined, and so more and more close-enough solutions will be seen.

Comment: Even using the recommended parameters, I'm still seeing about 5% of encryptions being decrypted by a simple minded crack.  NVars = 32, NEqns = 400, q = 2^11-9. This tells me that I ought to either become comfortable with adversaries learning a few bits of my message, or else stick with ECC and much larger key sizes.

Comment: If _"Is Fortuna possibly broken here? "_ is purely rhetorical, I suggest that you remove it, as well as _" (Fortuna)"_ and the [tag:fortuna] tag.